# WriteBack Error in OBIEE 11g

Tags: xml

While using writeback in reports I am getting

> system unable to read writeback template 'WriteBack' please contact ur sys admin

This is my XML template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<WebMessageTables xmlns:sawm="com.siebel.analytics.web/message/v1">
    <WebMessageTable lang="en-us" system="WriteBack" table="Messages">
        <WebMessage name="WriteBack">
            <XML>
                <writeBack connectionPool="orcl">
                    <insert> </insert>
                    <update>
                         UPDATE W_PRODUCT_D SET PRODUCT_NUM='@{c3}' WHERE ROW_WID=@{c0}
                    </update>

                    <postUpdate>COMMIT</postUpdate>
                </writeBack>
            </XML>
        </WebMessage>
    </WebMessageTable>
</WebMessageTables>
</WebMessageTable>
</WebMessageTables>
```

Answer (score 0):

XML is wrong because the tag WebMessageTable and WebMessageTables are closing two times. Try Removing the last two lines in your template.